# phpmysql inserts blank instead of value

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have the following function:

```
function insert($database, $table, $data_array)
{
# Connect to MySQL server and select database
$mysql_connect = connect_to_database();
mysql_select_db ($database, $mysql_connect);

# Create column and data values for SQL command
foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) 
    {
    $tmp_col[] = $key;
    $tmp_dat[] = "'$value'";
    }
 $columns = join(",", $tmp_col);
 $data = join(",", $tmp_dat);

# Create and execute SQL command
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table."(".$columns.")VALUES(". $data.");";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $mysql_connect);

# Report SQL error, if one occured, otherwise return result
if(mysql_error($mysql_connect))
    {
    echo "MySQL Update Error: ".mysql_error($mysql_connect);
    $result = "";
    }
else
    {
    return $result;
    }
}
```

The values in php are the following:

```
$content_table = "p_content";
$insert_array['title'] = $title;
    $insert_array['content'] = $content;
$insert_array['url'] = $get_source;
$insert_array['video'] = $video;
$insert_array['date'] = $date;
insert(DATABASE, $content_table, $insert_array);
```

The result of all this adds a row with id (key, autoimcrement), url, and date. Title, content and video are blank. If I echo title I get the correct result, if i var_dump the title I get string(15)"blablablabla", again correct.

Now if I hand set the $title = "asdf"; it is getting inserted correctly. Same goes for content and video.

table structure

id  int(8) unsigned NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment

title   varchar(1000)   YES     NULL

content longtext    YES     NULL

video   varchar(3000)   YES     NULL

url varchar(300)    YES     NULL

date    date    YES     NULL

Comment: What is the output of `$insert_array`? Try using `var_dump` or `print_r` to see the format and ensure proper SQL format.

Comment: Array ( [title] => "asjgalkjhgfdkjas". [content] =>   lqejrhgojiehrgakehlgkj [url] => http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.html [video] => [date] => 2013-02-17 00:45:46 ) 
This is how the print_r looks like and I have tried putting the insert query directly without the function but same result

Comment: this is part of a library, anyway, the insert works great if I hand code the values of every variable

Comment: Replace $insert_array with $data_array in your insert function. Do you get a date value?

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injection problems with this code. I don't know where these values are coming from, but even if they're not "external" data, you can still inject yourself with purely internal-generated data.

Comment: Test if you can insert a value when you replace $insert_array with for example $title. If that doesn't work you might now if you insert_array is to blame.

Comment: I just tested the code, its working, the problem you have is in either your database connection, or your values getting past to the function.

Comment: I know about the vulnerabilities, this is not actually my issue at hand, thank for the advise though

Comment: Oke, then show the table structure. To see if all the column types are set correctly.

Comment: Show the database table structure.

Comment: Also add the exactly how you assign the variables. For example $title = 'title';

Comment: I have added the table structure, for how exactly I assign the values is pretty impossible to add exactly. Simple example is $title = "<a href="asdf">asdgasfd</a>"; 
$title = strip_tags($title);

Comment: Oke, at quotes $title = ´(strip_tags($title))´;

Comment: Ok, as @Mr.Radical says, we need to exact examples of what you're trying to insert. Are there NULL values? Your fields allow NULL values but you're wrapping your values in quotes ''.

Comment: try replacing `$tmp_dat[] = "'$value'";` with `$tmp_dat[] = (string) $value;`

Also, could you show us how that `$tmp_dat[]` array looks after loop?

Comment: @Mr.Radical the quotes did the trick thank you!

Comment: Oke, glad that I could help. May a post the answer below? So you could accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding quotes to your variables. :-) The reason is that you MYSQL column types are set as VARCHAR. And inserting data requires that you surround your inserts with quotes.

B.T.W. if this is new code I would recommend to switch to the MYSQLI or PDO library.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function insert($database, $table, $data_array)
{
    # Connect to MySQL server and select database
    $mysql_connect = connect_to_database();
    mysql_select_db($database, $mysql_connect);

    $cols = array();
    $vals = array();
    foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) {
        $cols[] = "`" . $key . "`";
        if (is_int($value) || is_float($value)) {
            $vals[] = $value;
        } else {
            $vals[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
        }
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table
         . ' (' . implode(', ', $cols) . ') '
         . 'VALUES (' . implode(', ', $vals) . ')';

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $mysql_connect);

    # Report SQL error, if one occured, otherwise return result
    if(mysql_error($mysql_connect)) {
        echo "MySQL Update Error: " . mysql_error($mysql_connect);
        $result = ""; // FIXME should probably return false here
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT**

Your code and the above is potentially vulnerable to SQL Injections. Go read about them.